# Upadating different state in store calls every state to fire subscription Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Sorry about the title not sure how to explain it!

I have a store set up like so..

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pluck';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { State } from './state';

const state: State = {
    flowers: null,
    insects: null,
    colours: null
};

export class Store {

  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<State>(state);
  private Store = this.subject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

  get value() {
    return this.subject.value;
  }

  select<T>(name: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.Store.pluck(name);
  }

  set(name: string, state: any) {
    this.subject.next({ 
        ...this.value, [name]: state
    });
  }
}
```

now I have a service call that gets a whole lot of data and then sorts them into different arrays and then updates the different state objects in the store like so

```
getData() {
    this._service.getAllData()
        .subscribe((result) => {
           this.storeData(result);
        }
}

storeData(data: any) {
    let flowers = [];
    let insects = [];
    let colours = [];
    data.forEach((item) => {
       switch(item.type) {
          case 'flower':
              flowers.push(item);
              break;
          case 'insect':
              insects.push(item);
              break;
          case 'colour':
              insects.push(item);
              break;
       }
    })
    this._store.set('flowers', flowers);
    this._store.set('insects', flowers);
    this._store.set('colours', flowers);
}
```

now whats happening is I'm subscribing to colours for example like so

```
getColours() {
   this._store.select('colours')
      .subscribe((result) => {
         console.log(result);
      })
}
```

I get the `console.log()` 3 times because I am updating different items of state in the store 3 times in the storeData function... is this correct?? I was under the impression the 'colours' state would only be updated and thus call the subscription if 'colours' was updated not any state in the store??

Am I doing something wrong??

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Every time you call `.set()` on your store, you're replacing the value with a new object.

Comment: @Brandon I understand it replaces the whole value of the state I've set like this._store.set('flowers', flower) would replace anything thats in the flowers object, but why does it fire my entire store?? It should just fire the flowers

Comment: That's what I'm saying - it's not just replacing the value of the `flowers` key. It's replacing the entire state object.

Comment: Right.. how can I change the `set` to only update the flowers key?? I was under the impression thats how it worked.

Comment: With your current methodology, you'd need 3 separate objects, one for each key of your current state. Or, you could switch over to Ngrx

Comment: Here's a good tutorial based on a BehaviorSubject: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3522-creating-a-simple-setstate-store-using-an-rxjs-behaviorsubject-in-angular-6-1-10.htm  as you'll see from his code, the same thing happens when you update the state object, but you can prevent the subscriptions from firing every time the state changes by returning only when the value changes.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was - prevent the subscriptions from updating on every state change by using distinctUntilChanged. This way they only receive a new value when it changes, rather than every time state is updated.

Comment: there's a few typo errors : in `Store` class, `set` function : `...this.value` should be replaced by `...this.subject.value` and in `storeData`, you store `flowers` as `insects` and `colours`